# Facebook iframe application redirects to local server

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, redirect

I am using FaceBook application inside iframe. But when I try to access it using url like 
http://apps.facebook.com/myapp, it immediately redirects me to my lhttp://localhost:8080 application, which I intended to keep in frame.

I assume that my local application should stay in frame, while the general container would be FB site itself, but something is wrong.
Any hints?

Comment: Can you provide some more details about how your local development environment setup and which URL settings you have configured in your FB app?

Comment: This is most likely because of the SDK you're using. But more info would be helpful to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want play your application on facebook so you need set
param on login url and This option should be added  `canvas => 1`,
`fbconnect=>0`. I hope this will be resolved ur problem..